# How to update Mysql using array in php in a dynamic way

Tags: php, html, mysql

I made a post array when i print it,I am getting following output.

`Array
(
    [name] => gowtham
    [content] => Nice Website
)`

**where Key of array is a column name in my database and value is value in database.
i want to update my database using these values,but these values in post array changes basing on html form.**

i made a string using implode.

`$query ="UPDATE ".$_SESSION['table']." SET ".implode(' = ',$array);`

but my output is

`UPDATE testimonials SET gowtham = Nice Website`

i want output as

`UPDATE testimonials SET name = gowtham , content = Nice Website`

Please help me

Comment: Why do you keep the table name in a session?

Comment: if i sent it through post variable it might damage formate of array

Comment: O.o @GowthamRajVungarala HOW? Where you read or learn that from?

Comment: i tried it on my own i was successful in insert but failed in update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This approach is very insecure.  I would recommend using a db class that handles this stuff for you....I use the following : http://www.imavex.com/php-pdo-wrapper-class/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
$update = '';
$i = 0;

foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
    $update = $key . ' = "' . $value . '"' . ( $i == count( $_POST ) ? ', ' : '' );
    $i++;
}

$query ='UPDATE ' . $_SESSION['table'] . ' SET ' . $update;
```

Worth noting you may need to unset the submit button before you run the loop and if you need to update by an id you need to skip that in the loop and for the where clause separately, in a if statement would probably be easiest.

Also worth mentioning your should try and use PDO's or mysqli because the mysql_* functions in PHP are depreciated as of version 5.5.

PS - I know I didnt sanitise any of the data but you should!

Comment: Syntax error here: `"UPDATE ".$_SESSION['table']." SET . ' ' . $update` concatenation is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
$cols=array_keys($yourarray);
$cols=array_values($yourarray);
$colnames = "`".implode("`, `", $cols)."`";
$colvals = "`".implode("', '", $vals)."`";
$query="update tablename set ($colnames) values ($colvals)";
```